# How to design a function to read multi excel files and make a repetition calculation in R

Tags: r, readxl

I have a file contain a multi excel sheet, I want to run a function to read every sheet and subtract one column from another, then calculate a mean

I tried

```
library(readxl)

average_working_hours <- function(Name) {
    Name <- read_excel("~/Name.xlsx")
    hours12 <- 12*60*60
    av_wh_Name <- mean((Name$`Departure of staff`+ hours12) - Name$`Attendance of Staff`, na.rm = TRUE)
    av_wh_Name
}

average_working_hours(Name = Noha)

have an ERROR 
 **Error in read_fun(path = path, sheet = sheet, limits = limits, shim = shim,  : 
  Evaluation error: zip file 'C:/Users/user 2/Documents/Name.xlsx' cannot be opened.**
```

then I tried

```
average_working_hours <- function(Name) {
    Name <- read_excel(sprintf("~/%s.xlsx ",Name))
    hours12 <- 12*60*60
    av_wh_Name <- mean((Name$`Departure of staff`+ hours12) - Name$`Attendance of Staff`, na.rm = TRUE)
    av_wh_Name
}
average_working_hours(Name = Noha)

have an ERROR 
 **Error in switch(ext, xls = "xls", xlsx = "xlsx", xlsm = "xlsx", if (nzchar(ext)) { : 
  EXPR must be a length 1 vector**
```

where's the problem?

Comment: do you want to return a mean value for each sheet in your excel file?

Comment: subtract the time of departure - the time of attendance then calculate the mean to find the average working hours

Comment: right, so let's say you have a file with 10 sheets you want to get 10 values for average working hours?

Comment: yes, then I want to make a plot

Answer (score 1):

In the second code try calling the function using  `average_working_hours(Name = "Noha")`.
[Screenshot of the working code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdAvQ.png)

Comment: Error: Missing file extension.

Comment: https://scontent-cai1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/21272443_1120723514726066_1568475220429084587_n.jpg?oh=6e5eb163b5f24d36ae31f8dea53fce3d&oe=5A19F3D3

Comment: @norhanabdelaziz I edited my answer to include the screenshot of working code. Please check whether your extension of the file is **xlsx**. Also check the location of the file.